# Algorithm for non-contiguous netmask match

Tags: data-structures, network-programming, real-time, packet, performance

I have to write a *really really fast* algorithm to match an IP address to a list of groups, where each group is defined using a notation like 192.168.0.0/252.255.0.255. As you can see, the bitmask can contain zeros even in the middle, so the traditional "longest prefix match" algorithms won't work. If an IP matches two groups, it will be assigned to the group containing most 1's in the netmask.

I'm not working with many entries (let's say < 1000) and I don't want to use a data structure requiring a large memory footprint (let's say > 1-2 MB), but it really has to be fast (of course I can't afford a linear search).

Do you have any suggestion? Thanks guys.

UPDATE: I found something quite interesting at http://www.cse.usf.edu/~ligatti/papers/grouper-conf.pdf, but it's still too memory-hungry for my utopic use case

Comment: this makes no sense whatsoever - convert your netmasks to the regular kind, sort them from most to least specific, match them the traditional way.

Comment: I'm sorry but *your* comment doesn't make sense. A netmask 255.255.0.255 can't be converted to the "regular kind", and this is a useful situation if you have, for example, 255 networks where addresses in each network are assigned first to a specific type of host (e.g. all web servers are .1, so I want to group hosts 192.168.0.1, 192.168.1.1, 192.168.2.1, ...).

Comment: And BTW, even if I could convert netmasks to the traditional format, what you proposed is terribly slow, because it's O(N), and there are much better ways (e.g. binary search, radix tree, ...).

Comment: but in that case you don't match on the netmask but rather on the ip, now don't you? also, where did i say you couldn't use binary search or radix tree?

Comment: In that case I *DO* match on the netmask. I don't understand what you mean by "but rather on the ip". In my example I wanted to do a match like:

(IP & 255.255.0.255) == 192.168.0.1

which is, AFAIK, a match on the netmask, because it involves the netmask.


Regarding your algorithm suggestion, you said "sort them from most to least specific", but this is useless if you use an algorithm like radix tree (it doesn't matter the order you insert) or a binary search (simply sorting will not do the trick), so I don't understand why you said that.

Comment: It would be beneficial for you to include specific metrics on what "really, really, really fast" means.  In other words, state that you need to process x entries in p seconds.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many IP addresses you'll be dealing with initially, I'd say use a Hash Map structure.  For the keys of this map, convert the IP into an integer-type structure.  Hash Maps, assuming a good hash function (with no collision), will give you O(1) insertion and O(1) lookup.

If you don't know how many IPs you'll have, look into using a [Fibonacci Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) (which I *think* has the best time complexity out of all tree structures for insert/delete/lookup).

Another type of structure you could use is a [Radix Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Do you have any specific requirements on how long the algorithm must take?  "Really, really, really fast" is kinda vague.

Comment: Hi,
First of all, many thanks for your complete answer.
Some note:

1) Unfortunately I can't afford a hash table, because I can't assume what is the input from the user (and it can be something like /0.0.0.1, which will saturate any kind of data structure if "unrolled"). 2) Regarding the complexity, I need a lookup O(logN), where N is the number of entries inserted by the user. Then, I already keep a cache (a hash table) containing the last X addresses used during the lookup
(this way I get O(1) when I lookup an IP for the second time, which happens frequently in my typical usage case).

Comment: 3) I don't need a fast insertion and an online insertion (insertion in the data structure is made when my software module is started and can't be updated), and I don't need deletion.
4) Regarding the data structures you propose, they seem interesting, but I'm not figuring out the way to use them for my case, considering that this is not an "exact" lookup (i.e. I can have 192.168.0.0/255.0.0.255 and 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.255, and the IP 192.168.0.0 has to match the second entry). Thanks and merry christmas!

Answer (score 1):

You build a binary tree that checks the bits individually.  You order the bit-checks in a form that gives you the "bushiest tree".  You have a post order traversal, so that it checks full depth before exiting, thus returning the longest hit.

pseudocode

```
nodeCheck(bitVector, index){//  bitvector is ordering of IP address bits for bushy tree
if myVal=-2 (return -1); //mismatched bit encountered No point continuing.
lVal,Rval=-1;
if (Left !=NULL  && bitvector[index]==0) lVal=Left.nodeCheck(bitvector, index+1);
if (Right !=NULL  && bitvector[index]==1) rVal=Right.nodeCheck(bitvector, index+1);
if (lVal>rVal) return lVal;  // higher numbers have >= number of 1's in netmask.
if (rVal >-1) return rVal;
return myVal;  //the group that getting this far would place you in, -1 if none.
```

}

Sure for speed you want to skip the OO factor, but the concept is the same..
The logic is a bit wonky, but the idea is sound.

But given that you have the radixTree down I didn't want to bog too deep into it.
the post order traversal simply lets you grab the longest matching without getting too weird.

Comment: Many thanks for your response.
Probably I didn't understand well your algorithm, but how am I supposed to order the bit checks? I mean, suppose I have two entries like 0.0.0.0/255.255.0.255 and 0.0.0.0/255.255.255.0.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is *order your bits to fit your tree*. Make your tree as bushy (actually short) as possible.

more thorough answer:

Since these have the same length their order shouldn't matter
Lets Call 
0.0.0.0/255.255.0.255  A
0.0.0.0/255.255.255.0  B
incoming 0.0.111.0
octet    1 2   3 4  just so we have right ordering

And I'm going to do them by octets because I'm lazy.
To make the bushiest tree you need to check octet 3 or 4 as your first test 3 being the lower will take arbitrary precedence.

So this looks at the value, and checks the right hand branch.  The Right hand branch is another node,it checks octet one, and moves down the left hand branch, to the next node which checks octet 2, this checks the left (octet 4) and gets -1 (via NULL), the right and gets -1(via NULL), so it returns A (we'll call it an enumerated type).

So the octet ordering becomes 3 1 2 4.

Generally you want to order the bit checks so that early levels are doing some kind of check.  In this case we push the 4 to the end because if the three hits(was a zero) the check on octet 4 is a waste and doesn't need to be done.  But the 1 and 2 need to be done no matter the outcome of the first check.

on a larger problem there will be some nodes that have no check, sending them to identical left and right branches regardless of the value of the bit contained.

A poorly built valid tree could take an ordering of 3 4 1 2  so if the first check passes(0 instead of 111), the second check is a waste because we already belong in group B, no matter the value of octet 4.

Good luck.